# Why numba parallel=True is slower than parallel=False

Tags: python, parallel-processing, numba

I am trying to perform parallel computing using numba, however, I encountered a problem: using the following code, it is significantly slower if I switch parallel=True on compare to switching it off.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, prange
from numba.typed import List
import time


n = 1000

@njit(parallel = True)
def lamb(now):
    timez = List()
    k1 = List()
    k = 0
    for i in range(n):
        timez.append(np.arange(i+1))
        k1.append( len(timez[i][timez[i]<=now]) )

    for i in prange(n):
       k += k1[i]

    return k


lamb(21)

start = time.time()
lamb(21)
end = time.time()
print("Elapsed (after compilation) = %s" % (end - start))
```

If `parallel = True`, the elapsed time is `Elapsed (after compilation) = 0.012674093246459961`. In comparasion, if `parallel = False`, the elapsed time is `Elapsed (after compilation) = 0.007932901382446289`.

Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: 1) You are measuring compile time+runtime. parallel takes significantly more time to compile. You should be also aware of the fact that the global variable is a compile time constant. If you change it you have to manually recompile the function to see any effect. 2) At least with version 0.45.1 you would see that no parallelization is possible. If you measure only runtime you would see that the two versions perfom aprox. the same.

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting the same issue. The suggested answer here isn't helpful, since if I use `prange` using Cython, the parallel code is faster, so it's probably not OS related. "Then why not use Cython?", because numba is much quicker to implement and does not require setup.py files.

Answer (score 2):

Coordination between different processes adds a cost to performance. That is  the performance penalty you see, if the work was truly worth the effort to parallelize then you would reap net benefits assuming the work was large enough.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but with all due respect, this is not the answer to the question I am asking. I understand there is a coordination (communication) cost among processes, but the question is in which way the cost occurs?

Comment: Can you expand on that? So Python has to ask the OS "hey OS do you have resources to possibly give me access to another process perhaps?". So the OS now has to do some work and once it tells Python its okay to do that Python has does the work all while keeping track of now N + 1 stuffs and dealing with locks (lookup the GIL) and other administrative steps in between.

Comment: @skyindeer Use a sampling profiler if you want that question answered. It'll find you a much more accurate answer for your specific code (and hardware) than asking people here.